# how do i get new output dataframe in Pandas based on an if else statement numeric condition

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

Hi i have a pandas DataFrame , i need to get Date and Field_Worker by the amount Individuls_Confirmed(int) those equal or greater than 10 to be specific, i need to do it using if else statement or just a condition that would make it easy and reuse, thank you

> i am gettning (ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().)

In SQL i would do

> SELECT Field_Worker, Date FROM table WHERE Individuls_Confirmed <= 10

Here is my Code fairly new to python esp pandas

```
import mysql.connector

from tabulate import tabulate
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot

data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Selamola\Documents\R\MyrThings\Confirmations4748.csv')

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

csvData = pd.DataFrame(data)

if csvData['Individuls_Confirmed'] <= 10:
     print(csvData['Field_Worker'], csvData['Date'])


# print(csvData)
```

Sample of how DataFrame looks
[image: Table]

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as writing an SQL for same but the difference is here we dont write SELECT * from , just he query to filter:

```
df[<condition>]
```

which returns you a new df with filtered values. You can even pass the columns you need. In your case the query will be as follows:

```
csvData_filtered = csvData[csvData["Individuals_Confirmed"] <= 10][["Field_Worker","Date"]]
```

Comment: Please check dupe and correct answer.